# converting .sys to .inf file, is there any software or method to do this?

Tags: windows-7, conversion, file-conversion, inf

Converting .sys to .inf file, is there any software or method to do this?

I scoured the net and could not find any software or any explaining if possible and how. Any helpful responses welcome.

Comment: `.inf` files are usually use to install device drivers (`.sys` files).  They are not the same thing, so there is not really a conversion from one to the other.

Comment: Inf files are text, dll and sys files are binary, you can't convert from one to another.

Comment: **.inf** files tell Windows what to do with the actual drivers.  Where to install them what registry entries are needed, and where to copy the **dll,sys, and etc** files to and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sys` and `.inf` files are not the same thing, nor can one be converted to another.

- `.inf` files are text files that contain configuration information.
- `.sys` files are compiled binary device driver files

They are often found together when installing devices on Windows operating systems.

It sounds like you are trying to install a device on your computer, you should elaborate more in your question as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: what about .dll to .sys or .inf, possible?

Comment: no.  again, they are completely different type of files.  DLL are compiled programs meant to be called by other programs.

Comment: @ConverterProbs what are you trying to do, ***exactly***?

Comment: something pretty complex, but it depends on being able to do this, which according to you guys is not possible, oh well.

Comment: So tell us; so we tell you the proper way to do it

Comment: @ConverterProbs as ramhound said, thats what this site is for.  However, doing something predicated on doing something which isnt possible, doesnt make a lot of sense.  If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, then we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: kind of secret stuff, but i appreciate you guys chiming in and letting me know the scoop on the conversion attempt, reguards. pretty much all i needed to know. thanks again.